# ASP.Net MVC hosting to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to ASP.NET MVC Application and I have encountered a problem when I'm hosting the application to Microsoft Azure App Service.

I have hosted the application fine on Azure and it loads the index file fine but as soon as I enter my log-in details, it gives me an error 404: Verify message(Please see screenshots attached).

[Login page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itof1.jpg)

[Error message received after trying to log in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLlfD.png)

I did however notice that when I run the index page on my local machine locally, the application runs fine but when I select any other page and run the application locally on my local machine, I receive the same error as above.

Can someone please assist and help me figure out a way to host the application on Azure so that the index page is selected first and opens the index page?

NB. in the routeconfig file, the controller is set to "Home" and action is set to "Index"

[Screenshot of the routeconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA45F.png)

[Screenshot 1 of HomeController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFisi.png)

[Screenshot 2 of HomeController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txSHk.png)

[Screenshot 3 of HomeController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFKHB.png)

[Screenshot 4 of HomeController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swFjh.png)

[Screenshot 5 of HomeController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G77hV.png)

Comment: Hi. Were is your database? Are you still trying to access a local database while in Azure?

Comment: Hi, The database im using is SQL Server and no it is not a local database. The database is on a on-prem server

Comment: Can you post your Homecontroller.cs?

Comment: I have edited the post with the homecontroller for you to view

Comment:  You get redirected to the 'verify' route... Where is that in your project?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: Can someone please assist in helping me. Any sort of help will be highly appreciated <3

Comment: Can you make your visual studio solution available?

Comment: How do i make my visual studio solution available?

Comment: Maybe open a public repo somewhere (github, bitbucket,...) and post the link